# Возможно ли реализовать на jquery mobile прокладку маршрута.

Tags: jquery-mobile, javascript, html

Использоваться будут Яндекс-карты
Требуется следующий функционал:
 1. Прокладка маршрута между двумя точками
 2. Расстановка своих POI

Никогда с jquery-mobile не работал, сложно ли это реализовать?

Comment: jquery тут ни причем.

Comment: Т.е. можно? javascript+php?

Comment: апи яндекс карт такого не умеет? http://api.yandex.ru/maps/new_api.xml#mobile

Comment: Почему то на эмуляторе карты загружаются, а на смартфоне нет. 
Xperia S мой телефон. В чем может быть проблемаН